# Diagonalizability test

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I saw below theorem in my test book(by friedberg)

Theorem : a linear operator $T$ on $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over field $K$is diagonalizable "if and only if" **both** of the condition holds.

1) the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits over $K$

2) algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal to geometric multiplicity.

While in other textbook I saw **theorem** that,

Theorem: a linear operator $T$ on $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over field $K$is diagonalizable "if and only if" condition (2) of above theorem holds.

So which of these two theorems are true? First one or second one?

Further,

**If** 'first one' is true then can anyone given me example of linear operator $T$ on $n$-dimensional space which is **not diagonalizable** but satisfies condition (2). 
Thank you.

Comment: The second theorem is certainly false as stated, and as implied by the first theorem, any linear operator whose characteristic polynomial does not split over $K$ is a counterexample. Although perhaps $K$ is implicitly assumed to be algebraically closed, in which case it's fine.

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. No one helped me for this question(I asked it before 2days). Further, can you give me an example which shows that second theorem is false.

Comment: Do you know how to write down a linear operator with any characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Yes I know that...

Comment: And do you know how to write down a (separable) polynomial which doesn't split over some field?

Comment: For the second one , No I think..

Answer (score 0):

The second theorem is certainly false, any real matrix that does not have real eigenvalues is a counterexample.

If you add the condition

(3) ... and the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues is equal to the dimension of the space

then diagonalizability is equivalent to (2)(3).